# unable to launch HBase shell

Tags: java, macos, shell, hbase

I am able to get localhost:16010 running. But, somehow the Hbase shell is not launching when I use :

```
01HW993798:bin tcssig$ cd /Users/tcssig/Downloads/hbase-1.0.3/bin
01HW993798:bin tcssig$ hbase shell

-bash: hbase: command not found
```

When I directly launch Hbase Unix executable, it generates the below error log.

```
 Error: JAVA_HOME is not set
```

Although I have set it. After this only, the localhost:16010 is running.

NOTE : I know there is one similar question, but no relevant answers are present there.

Using this I am able to invoke the command, but now it gives the error :

```
./hbase: line 403: /Users/tcssig/Downloads/hbase-
```

``` 1.0.3/bin/JAVA_HOME:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Cont``ents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory ```

Although I have java file there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hbase invocation should be like this:

```
cd /Users/tcssig/Downloads/hbase-1.0.3/bin
./hbase shell  [Note the ./]
```

When you just type `hbase shell` linux searches for hbase executable in all directories included in `PATH` environment variable. Since above bin directory is not included it errors out.

Alternatively you can also update your path variable, based on linux distribution, the command to do that may vary. It should be something like:

```
export PATH=/Users/tcssig/Downloads/hbase-1.0.3/bin:$PATH
```

Put this command in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and then source this file. That way the bin directory is now included in PATH and `hbase` command is available.

Answer (score 0):

Go into `$HBASE_HOME/bin` path, and try:

```sh
./hbase shell
```